# I have a scenario where the customer number is changed often and now I need to find the last customer number that got assigned

Tags: sql-server

I have customer log table in SQL Server which records the customer number change

```
From_Cust#  To_Cust#  DateModified
A1          A2        1/11/2001
A2          A3        2/11/2001
A3          A4        2/11/2001
B1          B2        3/11/2001
B2          B3        3/30/2001
```

For certain customers the entry goes pretty steep like up to 200 level.

What I'm trying to get is to find the last changed customer no. value and apply it for all customer from the very first one.

```
From_Cust#  Latest_Cust#
A1          A4
A2          A4
A3          A4
B1          B3
B2          B3
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: A recursive cte can do this but ugh!!! Why do you change your customer number???

Comment: Do your tables have a timestamp indicating when the customer number was assigned?  Are customer numbers really alphanumeric and potentially duplicated, as in your examples?

Comment: I would try write a function to do that.

Comment: This sample data isn't  sufficient to answer this question. I'm guessing your Cust# aren't in that format, so firstly provide realistic values. secondly, if you have other columns that can be used to determine order, as in when they were added or an incremental ID, then this needs to be included in the question as given your data, there's no way to work this out.

Comment: The table has a date field indicating when the customer number got changed, other than this there is no incremental ID. And the customer numbers are numeric. I just made them as alpha numeric for ease of understanding the scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query that utilizes a [*recursive CTE*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
;WITH CustomerTree AS (
   SELECT From_Cust#, To_Cust# AS To_Cust#, 
          To_Cust# AS Latest_Cust#
   FROM mytable AS m1
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM mytable AS m2
                     WHERE m1.To_Cust# = m2.From_Cust#)

   UNION ALL

   SELECT m.From_Cust#, m.To_Cust#, c.Latest_Cust#
   FROM mytable AS m
   INNER JOIN CustomerTree AS c ON m.To_Cust# = c.From_Cust#
)
SELECT *
FROM CustomerTree
ORDER BY From_Cust#
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/97994/2)

The so-called *anchor member* of the recursive CTE:

```
SELECT From_Cust#, To_Cust# AS To_Cust#, 
          To_Cust# AS Latest_Cust#
   FROM mytable AS m1
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM mytable AS m2
                     WHERE m1.To_Cust# = m2.From_Cust#)
```

will select all records containing 'final' customers:

```
From_Cust#  To_Cust#    Latest_Cust#
-------------------------------------
A3          A4          A4
B2          B3          B3
```

The so-called *recursive members* of the CTE will fetch all records up the customer hierarchy.